# Finding number of jars in game folder with J2ME

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Kindly suggest me a way to find the count of an installed application in a mobile.

Also Is it possible to find the count of an installed application with a particular name.

Example :

1) if AA.jar,bb.jar,cc.jar are installed

```
  it should show count as 3
```

2) if AA.jar is installed twice

```
 it should show count as 2
```

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done locally with a MIDlet. The Application Management Software (AMS) does not provide an API for it.

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/j2menut_3/index5.html

Comment: Thank you telmo will get you soon.